# My question is showing as some others'

Tags: bug, support, users, unanswered-questions

I posted a question in https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ and someone modified the same. Right now in `Unanswered` section, the question is with his name as `Modified` title. Does the author has no importance in that view?

Answer (score 1):

The `Unanswered` view shows you the last person to have edited [the question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2061/106), which in you case was me, including the image for you; the `Questions` view shows you the original author.

I'm a little surprised that the two views don't behave in the same manner, but this may be "by design"

Comment: Is it an issue?

Comment: It's only an issue if you think it is - I'm not aware of anyone noticing in the past (and after all, the idea of an author is a little vague here, as anyone can suggest edits to any question or answer). I'm assuming you only wanted an explanation, as you didn't tag this as [tag:bug]

Comment: Should I reported this as bug? Because, modifying a question is just enhance the way of asking the question. So, I think OP should get higher importance than editor.